# Climage displaying part of the image in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

So I want to make a text adventure game with images in unicode, when I run the following code in the climage module:

```
import climage
  
# converts the image to print in terminal
# inform of ANSI Escape codes
output = climage.convert("F:/Tools/Examples/Climage/bruh.png", is_unicode=True, 
                         palette='default', is_truecolor=False)
  
# prints output on console.
print(output)
```

I run the program in debugging mode and I get the image but it is not full.

I also tried running this:

```
climage --unicode --truecolor Aristotle.png
```

I got the image full, but I cannot add it in the program in that way (that is what I know), so how can I fix that?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.